# Running Qt program with script causes program restart on exit

Tags: c++, linux, qt

The script file contains

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib/
echo "Line 1"
./LiveMonitor 
echo "Line 2"
```

The output is  Line 1
After closing  Line 1
               Line 2

What can cause such behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a display cache. Its actually just putting Line1,Line2, but the process being closed could trigger a partial refresh, which could cause the complete script output to be redrawn (now without the new-line from calling the script). Pipe the output of the script to a file and see if there are still Line1 twice before Line2.

```
./myscript.sh > log.txt
```

Comment: I tried to log the script output, but output is the same